# Flip key, value in a HashMap using Java8 Stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map` in following structure and I want to flip the key and value.

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataMap
```

Sample data :

```
acct01: [aa, ab, ad],
acct02: [ac, ad]
acct03: [ax, ab]
```

Want this data to be converted to,

```
aa: [acct01],
ab: [acct01, acct03],
ac: [acct02],
ad: [acct01, acct02],
ax: [acct03]
```

Want to know if there is a java 8 - stream way to transform the Map.

My Current implementation in (without Stream)

```
Map<String, List<String>> originalData = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        originalData.put("Acct01", Arrays.asList("aa", "ab", "ad"));
        originalData.put("Acct02", Arrays.asList("ac", "ad"));
        originalData.put("Acct03", Arrays.asList("ax", "ab"));

        System.out.println(originalData);
        Map<String, List<String>> newData = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        originalData.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            entry.getValue().forEach(v -> {
                if(newData.get(v) == null) {
                    List<String> t = new ArrayList<String>();
                    t.add(entry.getKey());
                    newData.put(v, t);
                } else {
                    newData.get(v).add(entry.getKey());
                }
            });
        });
        System.out.println(newData);
```

input and output,
`{Acct01=[aa, ab, ad], Acct02=[ac, ad], Acct03=[ax, ab]}
{aa=[Acct01], ab=[Acct01, Acct03], ac=[Acct02], ad=[Acct01, Acct02], ax=[Acct03]}`

Looking for way to implement using Stream.

Comment: Implemented using traditional way.. Still looking for way to implement using Stream()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the stream for the entry set, flatten it out into one entry per key-value pair, group by value, collect associated keys into a list.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

<K, V> Map<V, List<K>> invert(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(
        entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(
            value -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
                entry.getKey(),
                value
            )
        )
    ).collect(
        groupingBy(
            Entry::getValue,
            mapping(
                Entry::getKey,
                toList()
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution by Java 8 stream library: [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
newData = EntryStream.of(originalData).invert().flatMapKeys(k -> k.stream()).grouping();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using a third party library like [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can use a [ListMultimap](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/list/ListMultimap.html) (Each key can have a `List` of values). Multimap has [flip()](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/list/ListMultimap.html#flip--). So, this will work:

```
MutableListMultimap<String, String> originalData = Multimaps.mutable.list.empty();
originalData.putAll("Acct01", Arrays.asList("aa", "ab", "ad"));
originalData.putAll("Acct02", Arrays.asList("ac", "ad"));
originalData.putAll("Acct03", Arrays.asList("ax", "ab"));
System.out.println(originalData);

MutableBagMultimap<String, String> newData = originalData.flip();
System.out.println(newData);
```

input: `{Acct03=[ax, ab], Acct02=[ac, ad], Acct01=[aa, ab, ad]}`

output: `{ac=[Acct02], ad=[Acct02, Acct01], aa=[Acct01], ab=[Acct03, Acct01], ax=[Acct03]}`

Please note that `flip()` returns a [BagMultimap](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/bag/BagMultimap.html) where each key can have a `Bag` of values. [Bag](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/package-summary.html) is special data structure which is unordered and allows duplicates.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation already relies on features of Java8. The `forEach` method was added to a number of data structures in J8, and while you could use streams, there would be no point, as much of the advantage of streams comes from being able to execute filters, sorting, and other methods in a lazy fashion, which would not apply to key remapping.

If you really wanted to, you could sprinkle in a couple streams by changing all `.forEach` instances to `.stream().forEach` in your example.